# get $_REQUEST[''] value in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have implemented paypal payment into my(php) site. and when paypal return to my site it send the transection id as $_REQUEST['tx'] and i want to get it using javascript/jquery code.

I have tried this

```
function getUrlParameter(sParam)
{

   var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
   for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
   {
      var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
      if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
      {
       return sParameterName[1];
       }
   }
}    

var order_no='';
var pay_success = getUrlParameter('pay');
order_no = getUrlParameter('tx');
```

but this is working in $_GET['tx'] methode

mean url= http://example.com/services?pay=true&tx=63478568347657834
its working fine but not in case of $_REQUEST['tx'].
how can i do that ?

please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. POST data is not available on clientside. Instead, get it on the serverside and render into JavaScript:

```
<script>
  var tx = <?php echo json_encode($_REQUEST['tx']); ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: [Amandan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/240443/amadan) mean i can do it only in php not in js ??

Comment: I think you need remove first opened `<?php` and last closed `?>`?

Comment: Basically, yes. (I prefer "clientside vs serverside" to "JS vs PHP" because a) you could do it in JS if you were executing JS serverside, e.g. in a Node.js app; and b) you could do the same in, say, Ruby or Python or Java or whatever else you do, as long as it's on serverside.)

Comment: @Amadan NP )) P.S. And, of course, need to add quotation marks `"` ))

Comment: @stdob--: No, that's what `json_encode` is for. Handles quotes, handles escaping, and while not needed in this case, it also correctly handles arrays, numbers, booleans (as in, deliberately *not* putting them in quotes).